# Concurrent requests to static method with local variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, concurrency

If some concurrent requests to method below happend, Is there any chance of conflict or it is safe to use?

```
public static int? GetProfileId()
{
   HttpCookie loginInfoCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["LoginInfo"];
   if(loginInfoCookie != null)
   {
      return Convert.ToInt32(loginInfoCookie.value);
   }

   return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe, the httpcontext.current read the data from the execution context of associated thread, when you invoke GetProfileId in a normal way, I think there will be none conflict.